# unity-facebook-sdk score api

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-unity-sdk

I use facebook sdk 5.1 in my Unity3D project for iOS. When I post player new high score to facebook :

```
private const string scope = "email, publish_actions, user_games_activity, friends_games_activity";

public void PostResultsToFB(int bestScore) {
  var scoreData =  new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", bestScore.ToString()}};
  FB.API ("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, PostScoreCallback, scoreData);
}
```

Scores are posted to open graph. I can take it back from player and friends into my game leaderboards.

But I not see game stories on news feed and timeline.

I know story posted only when a player earns a new high score or beats a friend's score.

Comment: Hello did you manage to get it working? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your [Activity Log](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity) for the story, you might be missing the post on the wall.
2. Check that your app is not in the development mode. When an app is in dev mode the publishing will be successful on the developers/testers account only.

Comment: 1. No post in Activity Log. 2. App in dev mode, and I check Activity Log on the developer account.

Comment: So try by removing the dev mode

Comment: I make app available to the general public but nothing has changed. And I try post scores by facebook developers console, and nothing.

Comment: Checking the response is always good and helpful. Check the output of your call (`var response = FB.API ("/me/scores"....`) and let me me what error is it showing.

Comment: I cannot be, it must either return a `postid` or `error`. Try it in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) by selecting your app from the drop down on top right of the screen.

Comment: mm. If you are sure that post is not visible on wall/activity log; report a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/, they'll get back to you soon. Also post the bug link here so that other users may also subscribe to it.